# How do I predict future scenarios after training and validating my model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, caret

**Problem**

I'm new to machine learning and need a little activation energy to get me past this sticking point. I've trained/validated/tuned, and tested a random forest model. Therefore, I've used my entire data set and now want to use my random forest to predict (this is the whole point of creating a model in the first place). Theoretically and practically, how would I go about doing this? I'd like to use the model output and create a user defined function so that I can run the model on incoming data. I apologize for my noobness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole train/test/validation procedure is only used for two things, model selection and generalization error estimation.  Once you have picked the algorithm you will use and estimated its generalization error you need to then go back to your entire dataset.  Perform cross validation on the whole dataset to find optimal hyperparameters (but keep the generalization error from before).  This is your final model.  Save this object.  You can then use this object to predict future data using the predict function.
Some code may look like this:

```
#estimate error rate 

rf_trcontrol<-trainControl(method="cv",number=5)
rf_grid<-expand.grid(mtry=c(1,2,3)) 
rf.fit<-train(match~.,data=train,method="rf",trControl=rf_trcontrol,tuneGrid=rf_grid)

pred=predict(rf.fit,test,type="raw")

# Train final model
rf.fit.final<-train(match~.,data=train,method="rf",trControl=rf_trcontrol,tuneGrid=rf_grid)

save(rf.fit.final,file="fit.RData")

#predict future obs
load("fit.RData")

pred=predict(rf.fit.final,future.data,type="raw")
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and example code! I'm still a little confused with the `predict()` function. It seems like it produces a confusion matrix (with `table()`) but how could that happen when the `future.data` does not contain the binary column for which the confusion matrix/ `predict()` produces (i.e. how can the model say if there was a true positive when the `future.data` has no column for `match`)? I think an expanded example would be beneficial, if possible. Thanks much!

Comment: If there are any helpful links that explain how to develop a machine learning model beyond prediction of the test data set, that would be extremely helpful. Just spent the last couple days trying to track them down and they all stop at the test phase.

Comment: The predict function will give you the predictions on your future data. The output of that code I gave you will be simply a 1or0 (or whatever labels your problem has).  You can also adjust predict to output class probabilities if the algorithm supports that